# How can I send data from a tablayout fragment to the main activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, android-tablayout

I have a listview in my tablayout. When I click on one of these elements, I want that element to be added to a list in the mainactivity. So that I can display this list on another fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use interface when clicked on item
Create interface like this in one fragment

```
public interface OnClickListener{
     void onClick(Item listItem);
}
```

and in fragment create object like:

```
OnClickListener onClickListener;
```

and in onAttach assign the object

```
 @Override
 public void onAttach(Context context) {
super.onAttach(context);
    try {
      onClickListener= (onClickListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
       
    }
 }
```

and then implement this listener in your MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements onClickListener{}
```

and on button click in fragment pass the data to your MainActivity

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    onClickListener.onClick(YOUR_ITEM);
  }
});
```